# $(D^2) \cap (S^2 \setminus \{N\}) = D^2 \setminus \{0\}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to invoke Excision Theorem:

> For space $A, B \subset X$ whose interiors cover $X$, the inclusion $(B, A \cap B) \hookrightarrow (X, A)$ induces isomorphisms $H_n(B, A \cap B) \to H_n(X, A)$ for all $n$.

for the problem
$$H_n(D^2, D^2 \setminus \{0\}) \to H_n(S^2, S^2 \setminus \{N\})$$
It is clear that $S^2 \setminus \{N\} \subset S^2$. And after stereographic projection of $D^2$ onto $S^2 \setminus \{N\}$, we get $D^2 \subset S^2$. But it is not clear to me that $(D^2) \cap (S^2 \setminus \{N\}) = D^2 \setminus \{0\}$.

I see if I demand the stereographic projection from south pole will do - but (why) can I arbitrary pick from which pole to project?

Answer (score 1):

Under the usual definition of the (inverse of the) stereographic projection map, you're correct in saying that the the disk $D^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is mapped to the southern hemisphere of the sphere $S^2$.

This isn't a problem though because you just need some inclusion of $D^2$ into the sphere such that it contains the north pole $N$. Honestly, using stereographic projection is overkill. You know that the sphere is a manifold and so every point $p$ has a neighbourhood $U_p$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ which in turn contains a subspace $\tilde{U}_p$ (which contains $p$ still) which is homeomorphic to $D^2$. So, just choose $\tilde{U}_N$ to be the inclusion of the disk into the sphere containing $N$.

If you really want a solid map to use, then you can just compose the inverse of the stereographic projection map with the map $x\mapsto -x$ which is a diffeomorphism of the sphere. This maps the south pole to the north pole and the southern hemisphere to the northern hemisphere.