# The interior of $S^2 \setminus \{N\}$ is itself.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am hoping to confirm that if the interior of $S^2 \setminus \{N\}$ is itself? This question is in order to satisfy Excision Theorem condition in the exercise [$(D^2) \cap (S^2 \setminus \{N\}) = D^2 \setminus \{0\}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587851/d2-cap-s2-setminus-n-d2-setminus-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{N\}$ is a closed set, so $S^2 \backslash \{N\}$ is open by definition...

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't think of in terms of definition - I really should. Thank you so much for pointing that out for me, Seirios.